# asp.net multiple gridviews with radiobuttons

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I got two gridviews with radiobuttons on them. But I don't want them to be dependent on each other, for example.

Gridview 1:

- Value 1 - RadioButton
- Value 2 - RadioButton
- Value 3 - RadioButton

---

Gridview 2:

- Value 1 - RadioButton
- Value 2 - RadioButton
- Value 3 - RadioButton

If I select Value 1 in gridview 1, and I select Value 3 in gridview 3, my first selected radiobutton gets unselected.

JavaScript code:

```
    <script>
    function SelectOneDep(objId) {
        var grd = document.getElementById("<%=GridView1.ClientID %>");
        var rdoArray = grd.getElementsByTagName("input");
        for (i = 0; i <= rdoArray.length - 1; i++) {
            if (rdoArray[i].type == 'radio') {
                if (rdoArray[i].id != objId) {
                    rdoArray[i].checked = false;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    function SelectOneRet(objId) {
        var grd = document.getElementById("<%=GridView2.ClientID %>");
        var rdoArray = grd.getElementsByTagName("input");
        for (i = 0; i <= rdoArray.length - 1; i++) {
            if (rdoArray[i].type == 'radio') {
                if (rdoArray[i].id != objId) {
                    rdoArray[i].checked = false;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    </script>
```

Gridviewone:

```
<input type="radio" ID="rbDep" name="InpOne" runat="server" onclick="SelectOneDep(this.id);"/>
```

Gridviewtwo:

```
<input type="radio" ID="rbRet" name="InpTwo" runat="server" onclick="SelectOneRet(this.id);"/>
```

Comment: Seems like you need a radio button group. Each group of radio buttons should be in different group

Comment: Got any code example that shows me how to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add **GroupName** attriibute to the radio button to group them. By this, selection in one group will not affect selection in the other group

For GridView1

```
<asp:RadioButton GroupName="FirstGrid" id="rbDep" runat="server" OnClick="javascript:SelectRadiobutton(this.id)" />
```

For GridView2

```
<asp:RadioButton GroupName="SecondGrid" id="rbDep" runat="server" OnClick="javascript:SelectRadiobutton(this.id)" />
```

Comment: Hello again, unfortunately this doesn't work. I thought so, but still only works on one gridview. Is it maybe something wrong with my javascript?

Comment: Yes, your JavaScript might be doing some magic. Please confirm that.

Comment: I updated my question with an answer to my own question, afterwise i saw the button down below "Answer your question", is it possible to invert?